# Digitize points with attributes

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am new to GEE. I have an application where values can be set then points digitized.  I need to programmatically apply the values to fields(properties) while a user is adding points. I don't seem to find an API into the 'Configure geometry import' tool where the attribute field values can be set then applied to any new points that are digitized. I don't want a feature collection because each feature can have different values for the limited set of fields.

Anyone have an example of digitizing points and applying different values at different times while to user is adding points?

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work:

```js
var exportFeature = [];
var glbStatePostal = 'AL';
var glbUserID = 'rlf';
var glbNaipYear = 2017;
var glbColor = 'gray';
var glbEcoRegion = '79f';

// Archive folder in Assets tab
var outputFolder = 'users/XXXX/grgPointsArchive';

function displayExistingPoints(){
//Find existing point featureCollections
var existingTables = ee.data.getList({id:outputFolder});

//Iterate across each and read it in as a featureCollection
existingTables = existingTables.map(function(t){return ee.FeatureCollection(t.id)});

//Flatten the list of featureCollections into a single featureCollection
existingTables = ee.FeatureCollection(existingTables).flatten();

// Find the unique Colors available in pre-existing data
var Colors = ee.Dictionary(existingTables.aggregate_histogram('Color')).keys().getInfo();

// Iterate across available Colors
Colors.map(function(Color){
var existingTablesT = existingTables.filter(ee.Filter.eq('Color', Color));
Map.addLayer(existingTablesT,{color:Color}, 'Existing Points: ' + Color);
});

}
displayExistingPoints();
////////////////////////////////////////////////
//Add listener to map for clicks
Map.onClick(function(event){
//Find where user clicked and make a feature there
var point = ee.Geometry.Point([event.lon,event.lat]);
var f = ee.Feature(point, {'StatePostal':glbStatePostal, 'EcoRegion':glbEcoRegion, 'UserID':glbUserID, 'NaipYear':glbNaipYear, 'Color':glbColor});

//Append it to the list of session points
exportFeature.push(f);
print('GOT exportFeature ', exportFeature);
// show the points on the map as user enters them
Map.addLayer(point, {color:glbColor}, 'New Point: ' + glbColor );

});
function exportPoints(){
print('Exporting points');

var exportName = glbStatePostal + '_' + glbEcoRegion + '_' + glbUserID + '_' + ee.Date(new Date()).millis().getInfo().toString();

var assetId = outputFolder + '/'+ exportName;
var outFC = ee.FeatureCollection(exportFeature);
Export.table.toAsset(outFC, exportName, assetId);
exportFeature = [];
print('Exporting points...FINISHED');
}
var b = ui.Button('Export',exportPoints);
Map.add(b);
```